# Parsing an XML feed using Nokogiri isn't working

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is my code:

```
doc= Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php?rss/90d24f4ad98a2793", 'User-Agent' => 'ruby'))
search=doc.css('item')
if !search.blank?
  search.each do |data|
    title=data.css("title").text

    link=data.css("link").text
  end
end
```

but I did not get the link.

Comment: [What Constantin said.](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have as i defined above xml file and i want to extract            (http://www.click2houston.com/news/4-year-old-killed-in-pit-bull-attack/-/1735978/18207294/-/ffquspz/-/index.html)

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things are wrong:

```
if !search.blank?
```

won't work because `search` would be a NodeSet returned by `doc.css`. `NodeSet`'s don't have a `blank?` method. Perhaps you meant `empty?`?

```
title=data.css("title").text
```

isn't the correct way to find the `title` because, like in the above problem, you're getting a NodeSet instead of a Node. Getting `text` from a NodeSet can return a lot of garbage you don't want. Instead do:

```
title=data.at("title").text
```

Changing the code to this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc= Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php?rss/90d24f4ad98a2793", 'User-Agent' => 'ruby'))
search=doc.css('item')
if !search.empty?
  search.each do |data|
    title=data.at("title").text
    link=data.at("link").text
    puts "title: #{ title } link: #{ link }"
  end
end
```

Outputs:

```
title: Ex-Bengals cheerleaders lawsuit trial to begin link:
title: Freedom Center Offering Free Admission Monday link:
title: Miami University Band Performing in the Inaugural Parade link:
title: Northern Kentucky Man To Present Colors At Inauguration link:
title: John Gumms Monday Forecast link:
title: President Obama VP Biden sworn in officially begin second terms link:
title: Colerain Township Pizza Hut Robbed Saturday Night link:
title: Cold Snap Coming to Tri-State link:
title: 2 Men Arrested After Police Chase in Northern Kentucky link:
```

The `link` won't work because the XML is malformed, which, in my experience, is unbelievably common on the internet because people don't take the time to check their work.

The fix is going to take massaging the XML prior to Nokogiri receiving the content, or to modify your accessors. Luckily, this particular XML is easy to work around so this should help:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php?rss/90d24f4ad98a2793", 'User-Agent' => 'ruby'))
search = doc.css('item')
if !search.empty?
  search.each do |data|
    title = data.at("title").text
    link = data.at("link").next_sibling.text
    puts "title: #{ title } link: #{ link }"
  end
end
```

Which outputs:

```
title: Ex-Bengals cheerleaders lawsuit trial to begin link: http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php/sid/212072454/scat/90d24f4ad98a2793
title: Freedom Center Offering Free Admission Monday link: http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php/sid/212072914/scat/90d24f4ad98a2793
title: Miami University Band Performing in the Inaugural Parade link: http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php/sid/212072915/scat/90d24f4ad98a2793
title: Northern Kentucky Man To Present Colors At Inauguration link: http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php/sid/212072913/scat/90d24f4ad98a2793
title: John Gumms Monday Forecast link: http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php/sid/212070535/scat/90d24f4ad98a2793
title: President Obama VP Biden sworn in officially begin second terms link: http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php/sid/212060033/scat/90d24f4ad98a2793
title: Colerain Township Pizza Hut Robbed Saturday Night link: http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php/sid/212057132/scat/90d24f4ad98a2793
title: Cold Snap Coming to Tri-State link: http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php/sid/212057131/scat/90d24f4ad98a2793
title: 2 Men Arrested After Police Chase in Northern Kentucky link: http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php/sid/212057130/scat/90d24f4ad98a2793
```

All that done, you can write your code more clearly like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.cincinnatisun.com/index.php?rss/90d24f4ad98a2793", 'User-Agent' => 'ruby'))
doc.css('item').each do |data|
  title = data.at("title").text
  link = data.at("link").next_sibling.text
  puts "title: #{ title } link: #{ link }"
end
```

---

Interestingly enough, now the sample page appears to have its links fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html something like:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("feed.xml"))
@doc.xpath('//xmlns:link')
```

should do the job. But be aware, that your provided xml snippet isn't a valid xml feed at all (no root element, item tag not opened - only closed etc.). The code assumes the xml feed looks i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <item>
    <title>Atom-Powered Robots Run Amok</title>
    <link>http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03</link>
  </item>
</feed>
```

And extracts:

```
<link>http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03</link>
```

as result. Please try to to look at the documentation/reference first, if you have problems like this. If you tried something and it didn't worked like you would expect, than you can consult stackoverflow with actual code - that makes it easier to understand your problem & provide help.